# Using the Gamma Distribution

Tags: statistics

A company employs $N$ people, with their collective annual income in pounds being a random
variable with Gamma distribution with parameters $\beta = 1$ and $\alpha = 90000
N^{1/2}$. For each
employee the company pays £$15000$ per year.

(a) Find the expected income of the company as a function of $N$.
[2 marks]
(b) Find the expected net profit (note: net profit = annual income – costs) of the company as
a function of $N$. Find the number of employees which will give the company the highest
expected profit, and compute this maximum expected profit.

I am revising for a test I have got the net profit to be $90,000 N^{1/2}-15,000 N$ but not sure on the next step of $B$ please may someone answer it so I can see some structure, or give hints.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is simply the expected value of the gamma function, which is $$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$ This gives you the expected income.

In the question, you are told that the expected costs are $15,000 per employee, and the number of employees is N. Then total costs is 15,000N.

Then profits $p(N)$ would be $$p(N)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta} - 15,000N $$. Then you differentiate this function to find the optimal value for N and you should show that the second derivative is concave.